# Transposing in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

For the following table structure:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
|   timestamp   |   value1   |   value2 | ... value100 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|1/1/1 00:00:00 |     1      |    2     |    100       |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

How could I transpose it into a structure like this using Spark SQL syntax?

```
+---------------------------------------+
|   timestamp   |      id       | value |  
+---------------------------------------+
|1/1/1 00:00:00 | value1        |   1   |
|1/1/1 00:00:00 | value2        |   2   |  
|1/1/1 00:00:00 | ... value100  |  100  |  
+---------------------------------------+
```

In Python or R this would be relatively straightforward, and `UNPIVOT` doesn't seem to be applicable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more concise approach would be to use [STACK](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#stack)

#### Data Preparation

```
sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame([("20201021T00:00:00+0530",10,97,23,214),
                               ("20211011T00:00:00+0530",23,8218,9192,827),
                               ("20200212T00:00:00+0300",51,981,18,10),
                               ("20211021T00:00:00+0530",10,2197,871,108),
                               ("20211021T00:00:00+0900",128,9812,98,192),
                               ("20211021T00:00:00-0500",218,487,21,51)
                              ]
                              ,['timestamp','value1','value2','value3','value4'])

# sparkDF.show(truncate=False)

sparkDF.createOrReplaceTempView("sparkDF")

sql.sql("""
    SELECT 
        timestamp
        ,STACK(4,'value1',value1
                ,'value2',value2
                ,'value3',value3
                ,'value4',value4
        ) as (id,value)
    FROM sparkDF
""").show()

+--------------------+------+-----+
|           timestamp|    id|value|
+--------------------+------+-----+
|20201021T00:00:00...|value1|   10|
|20201021T00:00:00...|value2|   97|
|20201021T00:00:00...|value3|   23|
|20201021T00:00:00...|value4|  214|
|20211011T00:00:00...|value1|   23|
|20211011T00:00:00...|value2| 8218|
|20211011T00:00:00...|value3| 9192|
|20211011T00:00:00...|value4|  827|
|20200212T00:00:00...|value1|   51|
|20200212T00:00:00...|value2|  981|
|20200212T00:00:00...|value3|   18|
|20200212T00:00:00...|value4|   10|
|20211021T00:00:00...|value1|   10|
|20211021T00:00:00...|value2| 2197|
|20211021T00:00:00...|value3|  871|
|20211021T00:00:00...|value4|  108|
|20211021T00:00:00...|value1|  128|
|20211021T00:00:00...|value2| 9812|
|20211021T00:00:00...|value3|   98|
|20211021T00:00:00...|value4|  192|
+--------------------+------+-----+
```

#### Stack String

You can further create the `stack_str` , depending on the columns you want

```
col_len = 4
stack_str = ''

for i in range(col_len):
    if i == 0:
        stack_str += f'\'value{i+1}\',value{i+1}'
    else:
        stack_str += f',\'value{i+1}\',value{i+1}'

stack_str = f"STACK({col_len},{stack_str}) as (id,value)"

stack_str

"STACK(4,'value1',value1,'value2',value2,'value3',value3,'value4',value4) as (id,value)"

sql.sql(f"""
    SELECT 
        timestamp
        ,{stack_str}
    FROM sparkDF
""").show()

+--------------------+------+-----+
|           timestamp|    id|value|
+--------------------+------+-----+
|20201021T00:00:00...|value1|   10|
|20201021T00:00:00...|value2|   97|
|20201021T00:00:00...|value3|   23|
|20201021T00:00:00...|value4|  214|
|20211011T00:00:00...|value1|   23|
|20211011T00:00:00...|value2| 8218|
|20211011T00:00:00...|value3| 9192|
|20211011T00:00:00...|value4|  827|
|20200212T00:00:00...|value1|   51|
|20200212T00:00:00...|value2|  981|
|20200212T00:00:00...|value3|   18|
|20200212T00:00:00...|value4|   10|
|20211021T00:00:00...|value1|   10|
|20211021T00:00:00...|value2| 2197|
|20211021T00:00:00...|value3|  871|
|20211021T00:00:00...|value4|  108|
|20211021T00:00:00...|value1|  128|
|20211021T00:00:00...|value2| 9812|
|20211021T00:00:00...|value3|   98|
|20211021T00:00:00...|value4|  192|
+--------------------+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the same using regular SQL as follows

```
select timestamp
       ,'value1' as id
       ,value1 as value
  from table
union all
select timestamp
       ,'value2' as id
       ,value2 as value
  from table
union all
select timestamp
       ,'value3' as id
       ,value3 as value
  from table
```